# Ranking metric that takes into account length of result list?

Tags: ranking, recommender-system, metric

I would like to evaluate a problem where the user select an option from a list of variable length. The task is to provide a ranked list so that the item lower in rank is the most relevant.

If I use a traditional metric such as MRR, I get a high score for situations where the ranked list if very small (if there is 1 option, selecting the item at rank 1 is not better than random).

I was wondering what metric would be appropriate to evaluate such a system.